# Quantum Numbers/state multiplicity - specifically concerned with the differences between $L$, $l$ and $S$, $s$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

To put this into context, I will write out exactly what was on the lecture slide that confused me (I've also attached a picture, but I appreciate that text is preferred on here for search engine purposes):

> Carbon has a  configuration $(1s)^2 (2s)^2 (2p)^2$ in its ground state.
>
> The angular momentum stems from the $(2p)^2$ electrons in the partially filled $2p$ shell.
>
> In this case, the maximum value of $L$ consistent with the Pauli Exclusion Principle is $L_{\max} = 2$ **(*)**.
>
> So $L$ can take values $2, 1, 0$ with corresponding total spin angular momentum $0, 1, 0$ correspondingly.

Firstly, I'm not sure what he means by (*), so if someone could explain that, that would be great.

Now for the main issue. I understand that $L$ is total angular momentum and it is related to small $l$ by $L = \hbar\sqrt{l(l+1)}$. For the $(2p)$ state, $l=1$, so where does $L=2$ come from? Moreover, where does $L=2,1,0$ come from?

Likewise for the spin states, $s= \pm \frac{1}{2}$ and so I'm not really sure how we're getting these values for the total spin angular momentum, especially since I would expect them to be multiples of $\hbar$ by the formula $S = \hbar \sqrt{s(s+1)}$.

I have some familiarity with Hund's rules, but I don't think this relates to that as they come after this slide in my lecture course.

Any insight would be appreciated. As a side note, if someone could also explain what he means by $D(L=2)$ in the slide also, that'd be helpful!

[image]

Comment: There's sometimes a slight abuse of terminology when talking about these things. Oftentimes, people will use angular momentum when really the mean angular momentum quantum number. You get used to it.  The capital-L is the same as the lower-case l here, so when you say $L=\sqrt{\hbar l(l+1)}$, that's not correct in this context. S and D are (confusingly) letters that correspond to $l=0$ and $l=2$, respectively. So the S in spectroscopic notation means that $l=0$, and the $d$ means that $l=2$ (and $P$ means $l=1$, and there are some others).

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. However, why do we get $L=2$ in this example then? If the atom is in the $p$ orbital doesn't this by correspond to $l=1$ only (if we are taking $L$ to mean $l$)? Because $s$ orbitals have $l=0$, $p$ orbitals have $l=1$, $d$ orbitals have $l=2$ etc.. And how do we obtain the spin values?

Comment: I think I misinterpreted capital-L. I think it's likely that $L$ is supposed to be the total orbital angular momentum of the two electrons in the outer (unfilled) shell, and since  they are both in $l=1$ states, the combination of the two must be either $l=2$, $l=1$, or $l=0$. Finally, because these two-particle angular momentum states have different symmetry properties (under particle exchange), the corresponding spin piece of the wave function must have the corresponding (opposite) symmetry property under particle exchange (i.e. symmetric vs anti-symmetric).

Answer (score 1):

The lecturer is using $L$ and $S$ to refer to the total angular momentum quantum numbers, when the it might be better notation (and more standard) to use $l$ and $s$.  In practice, the quantities $\left|\vec{L}\right|=\sqrt{l(l+1)}\hbar$ and $\left|\vec{S}\right|=\sqrt{s(s+1)}\hbar$ are (pretty much) never actually useful for anything, so people sometimes just write $L$ when they mean the more useful quantity $l$.

As for $S(L=0)$ and $D(L=2)$, those are just reminders that we call $l=0$ atomic orbitals "$s$-states," and $l=2$ atomic orbitals "$d$-states."

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. However, why do we get $L=2$ in this example then? If the atom is in the $p$ orbital doesn't this by correspond to $l=1$ only (if we are taking $L$ to mean $l$)? Because $s$ orbitals have $l=0$, $p$ orbitals have $l=1$, $d$ orbitals have $l=2$ etc.. And how do we obtain the spin values?